# Passing an object between 2 view controllers not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to pass 3 objects to another VC but they are showing up as Null in the destination VC.

VC1:

```
- (void)specificExerciseTableViewController:(SpecificExerciseTableViewController *)specificExerciseTableViewController didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:(NSString *)exerciseURL muscleName:(NSString *)muscleName muscleURL:(NSString *)muscleURL;
{
    [self addExercise];
}

-(void)addExercise
{       
    PFObject *exerciseInRoutine = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"exerciseInRoutine"];
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.selectedExercise forKey:@"name"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.muscleName forKey:@"muscle"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine setObject:self.muscleURL forKey:@"picture"]; 
    [exerciseInRoutine saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];   
}
```

The class that is passing the objects to VC1:

```
 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(specificExerciseTableViewController:didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:muscleName:muscleURL:)])
                {
                    NSString *exerciseName = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
                    [self.delegate specificExerciseTableViewController:self didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:exerciseName muscleName:self.muscleName muscleURL:self.muscleURL];
                    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
```

Edit:

I've updated my method to set the objects to the VC's properties, but have same problem:

```
- (void)specificExerciseTableViewController:(SpecificExerciseTableViewController *)specificExerciseTableViewController didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:(NSString *)exerciseURL muscleName:(NSString *)muscleName muscleURL:(NSString *)muscleURL;
{
    self.muscleName = exerciseURL;
    self.muscleName = muscleName;
    self.muscleURL = muscleURL;
    [self addExercise];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect to happen when you execute the code shown above?

You second code block calls `-specificExerciseTableViewController:didSelectSpecificExerciseWithURL:muscleName:muscleURL:` on some `delegate` but the implementation of that method in your "VC1" example ignores the arguments passed to that method. You don't seem to be doing anything with the data you are given.

Comment: I've updated the question with my method to set the objects to the VC's properties, but have same problem:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing arguments to the delgate object.but inside the delegate method you didnt either pass the arguments to the function addExercise or assign the parameters to your properties before you call the metho.

Comment: check the properties for those variables.make sure you have retained the variables.